# How can I compare date string to datetime column in my database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, type-conversion

I have an array of days that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "18/09/2019"
    [1] => "19/09/2019"
    [2] => "20/09/2019"
    [3] => "21/09/2019"
    [4] => "22/09/2019"
    [5] => "23/09/2019"
    [6] => "24/09/2019"
)
```

And a `date` column in my database that contains `DATETIME` values, like: `2019-09-18 00:00:00`

Now I want to select all from my `orders` table where for example `date = 18/09/2019`.

How can I do that?

I tried the following but this gives me a syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE date = CONVERT(DATETIME, '24/09/2019')
```

I am using MYSQL.

Comment: SQL does not have a built-in type called "array" -- although some databases do.  Your question is not clear without a database tag and an explanation of where the array is coming from.  You should also specify what the syntax error is.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know that, but the example query shown below is how I end up checking in my database, so the array is not 100% relevant, it's just how my dates are looking that I am trying to compare to my `DATETIME` values in my database

Comment: @jarlh I had a SQL tag but for clearification I added it in my question

Comment: SQL is a languange supported by many products, with different variations. So which dbms are you using? (Do you perhaps mean MS SQL Server?)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using mysql

Comment: You should take a look at [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for MySQL:

You have to convert your `DATETIME` column values to `DATE` values using `DATE() function` and then compare them with your array values using `STR_TO_DATE` function with appropriate mapping:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE DATE(date) = STR_TO_DATE(array_member, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Oracle database:

You have to first truncate your `DATETIME` column values to `DATE` values and then compare them with your "array" values using `TO_DATE` with appropriate mapping:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE TRUNC(date) = TO_DATE(array_member, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

**Note:** I posted this answer before OP stated that he is working in `MYSQL`. Nevertheless, I'll leave it be for Oracle users who stumble on the same problem looking for answers.

Comment: Now that you have posted a correct answer for MySql then please remove this one since we are discouraged from posting multiple answers to a question.